# Android ByteBuffer get backing array

Tags: java, android, arrays, usb, byte

How can I get backingArray from ByteBuffer.
Here is my code

```
while (true) {
    for (String cmd : commands) {
        buffer.clear();
        buffer.put(hexStringToByteArray(cmd));
        request.queue(buffer, 1);
        if (connection.requestWait() == request) {
            if (inRequest.queue(buffer, bufferMaxLength) == true) {
                connection.requestWait();
                bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                buffer.get(bytes,0, bytes.length);
```

Comment: Explain first what this code does. Then tell what a backingArray would be.

Comment: I'm trying to communicate with USB device. I expect a response from usb device to be in backing array of ByteBuffer. I can see a backingArray with expected response in debugger window but I can get it as byte array.

Comment: A `ByteBuffer` has an `.array()` method for that; however, 1. this won't work for directly allocated buffers and 2. you will really get the raw array and lose all position/limit information. Maybe you want to use .flip() instead.